# php in_array multibyte equivalent

Tags: php, multibyte, mbstring

Is `in_array()` function in php multibyte safe?

If not ,how can i make it so?

The **php.net** multibyte reference lists `mb_stristr()` but it accepts a string , not an *array as haystack* .

My `haystack = array` of strings and `needle = string`.

Comment: You can always loop the array, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find any built in PHP solution, I did as @FirstOne suggested.

```php
/**
 * @return bool true if needle is found in haystack, false otherwise
 */
public function custom_mb_in_array($_needle, array $_hayStack) {
    foreach ($_hayStack as $value) {
        if (mb_strtolower($value) === mb_strtolower($_needle)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```